# Saving a .wav -file sent with Postman in Node.js using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, multer

I'm trying to send a wav file as a POST request to my Node.js API endpoint and save the file in the server. This is what I've tried to test Multer:

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "/uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("audio");


app.post("/api/upload", function (req, res) {
      upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
          // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
        } else if (err) {
          // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
        }
        // Everything went fine.
        const audio = req.files;
        console.log(audio);
      });
    }
```

But when I make a POST request with Postman to my endpoint I get `undefined` from `console.log(audio);` In my POST request I've put a key-value pair `audio: test.wav` in form-data section of the request body. What am I doing wrong and how can I access the wav file I'm sending so I could use it later?

I'm also interested to know if there's some better way to do what I want to do.

Edit. Are these right?

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: "true",
  })
); // Parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Parse application/json
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    type: "application/vnd.api+json",
  })
); // Parse application/vnd.api+json as json

app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: "audio/wav" }));
```

Comment: You made a typo. It should be `req.file`: **singular**

Comment: It is still undefined even if I change it like this:

`const audio = req.file;
console.log(audio);`

Comment: I tested it and it works for me. Maybe you forgot to change the field from text to file in postman or something.